# Typescript multiple type parameter

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to access the pos propery.

> error TS2339: Property 'pos' does not exist on type '{ pos: RoomPosition; } | RoomPosition'.

```
public moveTo(target: RoomPosition | { pos: RoomPosition }, opts?: FindPathOpts): number {
  ..
  if (target instanceof RoomPosition && !target.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
    ..
  } else if (!target.pos.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
    ..
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typescript type guards aren't very smart.
If you'll do this:

```
if (target instanceof RoomPosition) {
    ...
} else if (!target.pos.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
    ...
}
```

Then it won't complain about the `target.pos`, but because your first `if` contains more logic to it other than the type of `target` then the compiler doesn't deduce that if that `if` fails then it means that `target` is now `{ pos: RoomPosition }` (which is correct as it can fail for another reason).
The next [typescript version (2.x)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) will be smarter, but not sure if it will be better in your case.

How about doing it like this:

```
public moveTo(target: RoomPosition | { pos: RoomPosition }, opts?: FindPathOpts): number {
    ...

    if (target instanceof RoomPosition) {
        if (!target.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        if (!target.pos.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

When you use a union type, you can only access properties that are *common* to both types - as they are the only properties Typescript knows for sure will be on the variable.

To access the variable that is only available on a given Type, you need to use a type assertion.  You can use an explicit type assertion e.g.

```
if (target instanceof RoomPosition && !target.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
  ...
} else if (<{pos:RoomPosition}>target.pos.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
  ...
}
```

You should also restructure your code a bit, as the else condition may be triggered even if target is a RoomPosition, but it is not equal to the destination, and that may cause a runtime issue accessing .pos in the else clause.  The following is safer:

```
if (target instanceof RoomPosition) {
    if (!target.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
      ...
    }
} else if (<{pos:RoomPosition}>target.pos.isEqualTo(destination.x, destination.y)) {
  ...
}
```

It might also be worth defining a named type or interface to represent `{pos:RoomPosition}`.

There are other syntactic ways of achieving the same thing - see the doc above for user defined type guards and some of the other mechanisms for working with union types.

Comment: The problem is that these type assertions create unreadable code, it's way too verbose, which is why there are type guards.